# Tree Data Structure to load huge datatable 800K rows - 30K+ branches

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, tree, structure

have a task to do some calculations based on a hierarchical data structure 
tried this great class from https://www.siepman.nl/blog/a-generic-tree-of-nodes-the-easy-way but loading my datatable (CreateTree) is taking forever.

my C# skills are a bit rusty, is there any way to tweak this an make it faster or convert it to multi-threaded or any other Tree Class that I could use?

Tried to find another class that can load my data without any luck so far

thanx in advance

Comment: Does the end-user really want to view 800K rows?

Comment: no, only the results of the calculations

Comment: The get location is a list which take N/2 searches to get an item.  If you make it a Dictionary with a hash it will improve the execution time.